# Apply CSS to single instance of Custom user Control in ASP:NET

Tags: asp.net, css, custom-controls, instance

Ok I created simple user control that look like this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PlaceHolderCMS.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_PlaceHolderCMS" %>

<div id="contentPlaceholder" runat="server" class="contentPlaceholderStyle">
</div>
```

I am using it like this

```
<div class="mainField" runat="server">             
  <cms:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderCMS1" runat="server" class="PH1" />
  <cms:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderCMS2" runat="server" />
</div>
```

But my problem is CSS, I can edit styles that is asociated with entire control, like this

```
.contentPlaceholderStyle
{
    border-style :dashed;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-width:1px; 
    padding: 10px, 10px, 0px, 0px;  
    margin:15px;
    height:100px;
}
```

But when i try to style single instance of user control **nothing** happens. I tried this from stylesheet, like this

```
.PH1
{    
    height:100px;
}
```

and from C#, like this
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
PlaceHolderCMS1.Attributes["style"] = "width=" + width + "%; height:" + height + "px;" ;
```

}

So my question is how can I put style attributes for instances of my Custom Control? I want to have general styles for entire control, and override them for particular instances if needed.

Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that UserControl doesn't render any tag for himself. Since that it's nothing to apply your class on. So it's abolutely on you to provide some custom CssClass property for your control and assign this to some container that holds all your control children.

Control's markup:

```
<div class='<%= CssClass %>' >
    <div id="contentPlaceholder" runat="server" class="contentPlaceholderStyle">
    </div>
</div>
```

Control's code-behind:

```
[CssClassProperty]
public string CssClass
{
    get { return (string)(ViewState["CssClass"] ?? ""); }
    set { ViewState["CssClass"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: I changed my UserControl in the way you suggested, and i tried applying CssClass property in .aspx, like this `<cms:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderCMS1" runat="server" CssClass="PH1" />`, but still nothing happens. Css is same as before... Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would likely be to have multiple classes on the control. During initialization of the control you could add the default class to any defined by your code, ie:

```
this.CssClass += "contentPlaceholderStyle";
```

in your initialization.

Comment: I could do that, but my problem is that I cannot access styles from code. Example PlaceHolderCMS1.Styles.Add cannot be accessed it return error .

Comment: @stanislav, Sorry, I was talking about in the control class itself, you sould also be able set a property for example and set the class in the .aspx file using something like: <div id="contentPlaceholder" runat="server" class="contentPlaceholderStyle <%# MyClass %>">

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be applying styles to the user control itself, but what you want to do is apply styles to the outermost div in your control.  That shouldn't work unless you override the properties of the user control to reference the properties of the outermost div.