# applying different styles on current page button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, sitefinity

I am doing a web site in asp.net (making user controls) and use them in sitefinity pages. 
My navigation bar button(s) is also a user control which is placed in a template.

Requriement is on current page button for that page should have different styles (color & bgcolor).

I am not getting how to implement this requirement. Guidance request please.

**Edit:**
I am not getting how to apply class on selected page. How to know in user control which page is current page. As both are separate user controls being used in a sitefinity page.

Thanks

Comment: you can use themes and skins in asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a specific requirement around using a custom control for your navigation? If you use the Navigation control that comes with Sitefinity (it's in the widget dock) - it will automatically add a CSS class ("rtSelected") to the selected page

Answer (score 1):

Using themes, you can easily customize your server controls with the pre-defined looks bundled with the .NET Framework or can make your own themes according to the look and feel of your website. try this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11886/Themes-and-Skins-in-ASP-NET-2-0

EDIT #1

try this link

[How to make user controls know about css classes in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390/how-to-make-user-controls-know-about-css-classes-in-asp-net)

and

[Apply CSS to single instance of Custom user Control in ASP:NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288728/apply-css-to-single-instance-of-custom-user-control-in-aspnet)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you can get ready made themes by using `telerik controls`.

You can write css code for it as you want and then give link to that css as follows>>

```
 <MyUserControls:MyMenuButton ID="SalesDocumentsMyMenuButton"
                    RootMenuItemText="Sales Documents"
                    RootMenuImage="~/images/common/sales_document.gif"
                    UseSeperator="true"
                    CssClass="css/myButtonMenu.css"
                    runat="server" />
```

You can also write css for codebehind for particular control as>>

```
<div class='<%= CssClass %>' >
    <div id="contentPlaceholder" runat="server" class="contentPlaceholderStyle">
    </div>
</div>

[CssClassProperty]
public string CssClass
{
    get { return (string)(ViewState["CssClass"] ?? ""); }
    set { ViewState["CssClass"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: you can identify current page by HttpContext.Current.Request.Url property or this.Page property

Answer (score 0):

You can create different themes and use it according to your condition.
Themes will contain different css files.
Create css-classes with same name but with different color or background-color
And use that theme according to your condition

Example

```
protected void BasePage_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Page.Theme = themeName;
 }
```

Here is a tutorial
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/10/how-to-change-page-theme-dynamically-in.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18300/How-to-change-page-theme-in-asp-net-2-0-dynamicall

http://aspalliance.com/959_Themes_and_Master_Pages_in_ASPNET_20__A_Perfect_Combination.4